# express-session with MongoStore working in Postman but not working in browser

Tags: middleware, mern, express-session, connect-mongo, mongostore

I am using MongoStore to store session.
Following snippet initializes the usage of express-session and MongoStore

```
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";

app.use(session({
    secret: env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 //one hour
    },
    rolling: true, //refresh cooking key as long as user is using the app
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING
    })
}));
```

The server side code for login is as follows:

```
export const login: RequestHandler<unknown, unknown, loginBody, unknown> = async (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        if (!username || !password) {
            throw createHttpError(400, "Parameters missing");
        }

        const user = await Usermodel.findOne({ username: username }).select("+password +email").exec();

        if (!user) {
            throw createHttpError(401, "Invalid Credentials");
        }

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password as string);

        if (!passwordMatch) {
            throw createHttpError(401, "Invalid Credentials");
        }

        req.session.userId = user._id;
        // req.session.save();
        console.log("=======login and return========");
        console.log(req.session);
        console.log("=======login and return========");
        return res.status(201).json(user);

    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

For which I get following output:

```
=======login and return========
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-12T12:39:35.226Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  userId: new ObjectId("64ad134f22c49e34a7b08237")
}
=======login and return========
```

But in the middleware code, this userId is absent in request.
Following is the snippet of middleware:

```
export const requiresAuth: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("========inside middleware==========");
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log("========inside middleware==========");
    if (req.session.userId) {
        next();
    } else {
        next(createHttpError(401, "User is not authenticated"));
    }
};
```

The output from middleware is:

```
========inside middleware==========
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-12T12:39:35.420Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
========inside middleware==========
```

As you can see clearly, property "userId" is missing from request.

I can also see records in "sessions" collection in MongoDB.

Ironically, everything works fine while using Postman client, but doesn't work in any browser.

Comment: please share your frontend code. I am assuming you are using some kind of form to send the data to backend?

Comment: await fetchData. you using fetch api?

Comment: Following is the code for calling API from the front end:

```export interface LoginBody {
    username: string,
    password: string
}

export async function login(credentials: LoginBody): Promise<User> {
    const response = await fetchData(BASE_URL + "/users/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    })

    return response.json();
}```

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury, yes I am using fetch api call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check the server-side CORS configuration and ensure that it allows credentials (cookies) to be included in the request. The server should respond with the appropriate CORS headers, including Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials. 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' should NOT BE '*'. Review and adjust the CORS configuration to allow the inclusion of credentials.
then Include cookies with the request

```js
export async function login(credentials: LoginBody): Promise<User> {
  const response = await fetch(BASE_URL + "/users/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    credentials: 'include', // Include cookies with the request
  });

  return response.json();
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then I don't get any response. "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier"

Comment: what your middleware logs says now?

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't even hit the url endpoint

Comment: double check your fetch apis url. cross check it against ur postman url. See if it matches with where the request is being sent. use Developer tools network tab to verify that your postman url and network tabs url matches. credentials: 'include' line should not have any effect on target. this is really strange.

Comment: They do match ```http://localhost:5000/api/users/login```
In the postman I get this response:
```{
  "_id": "64ad134f22c49e34a7b08237",
  "username": "mubin",
  "email": "mubin@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$YfpbD9UAuuEFtO3FWKM4d.MQnbLAYKOkA0qacstIDcp5NXIwMXjuG",
  "__v": 0
}```

Comment: can you check which url your fetch api is hitting when you make the call from your frontend? check the network tab from developer console.

Comment: From the network tab:
```Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/users/login```

Comment: then it is indeed hitting the endpoint. please tell me what is the response you get. and what is the status code?

Comment: There is no response. From the network tab: "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier"

Comment: really really really strange. please put a console.log({req}) inside the middleware and check what get's printed on the server's terminal?

Comment: If I remove the line: ```credentials: 'include',```
then api endpoint is hit and I am back to where I started, no "userId" in request object

Comment: tell me about your backend. are you using express?

Comment: {
  req: <ref *1> IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      constructed: true,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,

Comment: Yes I am using express

Comment: I believe this is a CORS issue. This is the only explanation i can think of. i am going to update my answer to add this.   Check the server-side CORS configuration and ensure that it allows credentials (cookies) to be included in the request. The server should respond with the appropriate CORS headers, including Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials. Review and adjust the CORS configuration to allow the inclusion of credentials.

Comment: I have already handled cors. Following is my code in app.ts
```import cors from 'cors';
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I have also added the following code:
```app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true')//true as string
    // res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
    // 'Date, Etag, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Set-Cookie, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials')
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PATCH,POST,DELETE");
        return res.status(200).send()
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: Credential is not supported if the CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is '*'. app.use(cors({
      credentials: true, origin: 'your url'
    }));

Comment: I tried it and console log of req.session gives:
```Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-07-12T15:14:38.538Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true
  },
  userId: new ObjectId("64ad134f22c49e34a7b08237")
}```
But it doesn't give any response even though I am returning it:
```return res.status(201).json(user); ```

Comment: excellent! So the authentication problem is solved! I don't see your full code for login RequestHandler. So I don't see within your code where the user actually coming form. so i cant help. are you retrieving the user from a database? if so, then what is the query you are using? are you using mongoose? i need to see more of your handler code. please edit your original question and add some more code.

Comment: Actually authentication was never a problem. The only problem is express-session not storing data. I am using Mongoose for DB queries. RequestHandler is a package from express: ```import { RequestHandler } from "express";```
I'll update the login code in the original question

Comment: Nah authentication definitely would have been a problem had you not passed the cookie successfully for protected url. Anywayz. in this line, const user = await Usermodel.findOne() if you log the user here, what do you get?

Comment: ```{
  _id: new ObjectId("64ad134f22c49e34a7b08237"),
  username: 'mubin',
  email: 'mubin@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$YfpbD9UAuuEFtO3FWKM4d.MQnbLAYKOkA0qacstIDcp5NXIwMXjuG',
  __v: 0
}```

Comment: so clearly you are retrieving your user successfully. now i think an error is happening after that line. please do a console.log of error in your catch block. don't use next() in your handler function. only in middleware use it.

Comment: Not using next().
Console log of session object, pasting from above:
```Session {   cookie: {     path: '/',     _expires: 2023-07-12T15:14:38.538Z,     originalMaxAge: 3600000,     httpOnly: true   },   userId: new ObjectId("64ad134f22c49e34a7b08237") }```

Comment: i am talking about login: RequestHandler. you are calling next method in the catch block. don't. instead do a console.log() of the error.

Comment: next method only to be used in middlewares. unless you have an error handler setup. but then we don't get to see the error that happens within the try block.

Comment: I am not getting anything in response to log even though the last line indicates:
```return res.status(201).json(user);```

Comment: okay so the problem is, within the login handler function, although user is fetched from db, the user is not being sent with response. that's the problem. right?

Comment: Yes. I am just getting status 201. But not the content.

Comment: Changed the code to this:
```return res.status(201).send("User logged in successfully");```
but still no response in the network tab

Comment: i am baffled! that means this line of code is never being executed at all. as i suspected. There's an error happening between fetching the user from db and the return statement.

Comment: login: RequestHandler functins catch block, update it like this, catch(error){console.log(error)} remove the next() method from there. then check if the error being logged in the terminal window of the server.

Comment: The flow is not going inside the catch block.

Comment: okay. one final try. update this line.. const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username }).select("+password +email").lean().exec();   i have added lean() method before exec(). now do return res.send(user)

Comment: Nothing. Just 201 status code. No content

Comment: you can log the user fetched from db inside the handler, then there are not error happening between this line and return statement, because you are not seeing any error being logged inside the catch block, yet the return statement is not being executed. yet you are getting a return with a status code 201 everytime. Sorry bud, I have never faced anything weird like this. I tried. keep at it. You will figure it out. eventually. Good luck!

Comment: I am getting response now. The issue was that I didn't comment line:
```app.use(cors());```. 
Having only: ```app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));```
So "user" is coming as json response but now the original question still troubles.
Request object is not showing the userId property

Comment: That's great! Verify the order of middleware: Confirm that the requiresAuth middleware is placed after the session middleware in the middleware chain.

Comment: i will strongly recommend using a library for session management. look into passport.js.